# Need help to plot diuranal variation plot for mydata

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a data in `.csv` format for one month in folder as well as years respectively. I am able to read it for one day but not for all days?

I have used this code to read file:

```
files = dir('*.csv') / *to create dir
num_files = length(files); / * to find length (32 includes datalog.csv file also)
for  i=1:num_files
     data = dlmread(files(i).name)
     data{1} = datenum(data{1});
end
```

Working for directory, file names such as:

```
GG010316.csv,GG020316.CSV...........GG310316,DTATALOG.CSV; /
```

And Data formatted as `dd-mmm-yyyy` in the first column, and time in 2nd column

I want to run program for one month, I want loop this data format.

Comment: The variable `data` is over-written on every loop. When the loop ends, it will have only the file for the last day in the list.

Comment: thanks for ur suggetions but please help me to read this kind of data sets for year... i have to work on in.